# Java 8 : <identifier> expected

Tags: java, identifier

Here is my code:

```
CloseableHttpResponse closeableResponse = callApi(request);
int status = closeableResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
logger.info("Response Code : {}", status);

StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader rd = null;
try (rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(closeableResponse.getEntity().getContent()))) {
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }
} finally {
    if (rd != null) rd.close();
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> identifier expected in this below line:
>
> rd = new BufferedReader(
> InputStreamReader(closeableResponse.getEntity().getContent())))

Any idea on this? I have defined all variables. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: you don't set the type of rd

Comment: sorry, I noticed that my full code is missing. I added my full code.

Comment: Change `try ( ... ` to `try { ... `

Comment: It is giving sonarqube issues if I give try {}. This is the sonarqube issue: 

Try-with-resources should be used

Comment: That is because `try (...` and `try {...` are different things. sonarqube is right and you tried to do the right thing!

Comment: I cannot checkin code with a sonarqube critical issue with "Try-with-resources should be used "

Answer (score 5):

Using *try-with-resources* requires you to declare the variable **in** the [*try-with-resources*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement.

Like this:

```
try (BufferedReader rd = getBufferedReader()) {
    // your main code
}
```

Comment: Then why are you using try-with-resources @MalarKandasamy if you need to manually close it for whatever reason then just use regular try-catch

Comment: Read my comments above. I am getting sonarqube critical issue. Java has to improve its exception behaviour and give suggestions for getting rid of this.

Comment: I just told you how to get rid of it... if you don't want to have java close the stream for you then don't use try-with-resources @MalarKandasamy